# XAMPP server on Linux uses "nobody" user

Tags: linux, sudo, xampp

I have XAMPP server installed on Red hat . I find the when ever I execute PHP scripts it executes from the owner of "nobody".

Now the problem is I need to use sudo to run some process inside the PHP script .
if i use sudo , this owner "nobody" doesnt have the permission .

How do I run the scripts with different owner name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid XAMPP. RedHat, like any common distro already provides Apache, MySQL and PHP with real security support and correct integration.
http://www.apachefriends.org/fr/xampp-linux.html#1053

What you want is probably this sudo parameter, but I don't think it's a good idea too:

`nobody  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/youcmd`

Comment: Agreed - XAMPP is meant to be used on a desktop machine as a development environment. It's folly to use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your in built operating system's packages. That will set things up so that things run on the right permissions.